# If container width, padding and line-height is known, how to calculate height?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding element dynamically to DOM.

```
$('<div class="entry"></div>').text(data.status).appendTo(app.twitter_feed);
```

I want to get element height before it is added to DOM. The usual approach is to add the element within a hidden element with the same style and then simply see what is the height.

Though, is it imposible to calculate element height if you know container's width, padding and line-height (content is only plain-text) and content?

Comment: A rough gauge: inner height := line-height + padding + border (for single line content)

Comment: @Jack, Sorry, I forgot to add `content` (text) to the given data.

Comment: I've tried to implement solutions like that before but eventually I just use the old trick you mentioned. Seems the easier less error prone way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the content wraps inside a container may depend on browser and zoom level, so unless you're very sure the content will never wrap, I would advise determining the height the way you have described.

Comment: Forgot zoom! Yes, with thats close to impossible.

Comment: Zoom will have no effect to this problem as width/heigth/font-width is zooming as same percent.

Comment: @EnesUnal it should, but I've seen enough cases that don't play nice with that theory.

Comment: I agree that it cannot be done but my case is that it's not releated with zoom level but it may change from browser to browser. Try to zoom some page and see. 've a good day.

Answer (score 0):

If your text font is mono-sized-font, yes you can calculate it with formula `[(text-length/(width/char-width))]`, but I'm sure you are not using mono-sized-font like courier, monospace etc.

Answer is this : there is no way to do this with multi-sized-fonts, me sorry.