# Will the element be visible If it is added to DOM and instantly removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Will the element be visible *even for a blink of an eye* If it is added to DOM and instantly removed?

```
var feed    = $('<div class="entry"></div>').text(data.status).appendTo(app.twitter_feed);

console.log(feed.height());

feed.remove();
```

I've tried the above code on a few browsers and couldn't see the element. But is this behaviour consistent through all platforms/browsers?

Comment: What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: But is this behaviour consistent through all platforms/browsers?
You can test it yourself in all browsers right?

Comment: depends on how quickly JavaScript engine works. I won't recommend this though. Please state your problem and maybe someone could provide a better solution

Comment: @EswarRajeshPinapala, I did test it on all browsers using Mac/OSX. It could act very differently on PC or Linux, or machine with poor graphics card.

Comment: Try `setTimeout(function(){   feed.remove()  },1000)`, and see what is happened

Comment: It should be visible for a short time because you do `.height()` which requires a reflow. If you remove that, then it should not be visible in any browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151668/if-container-width-padding-and-line-height-is-known-how-to-calculate-height) as well, it seems that you very badly want to calculate the display height of an element before actually displaying it. I 'm not entirely clear *why* you want to do this (it gives off a bad smell), but here's how to anyway.

Put a `<div>` in your page with `height: 0`, `overflow: hidden`, and the desired width of your element¹. Add the `<div>` we 're talking about inside that outer helper div (it will not show no matter what), and get its height after the browser performs layout. After that you can proceed however you want (e.g. by moving the inner `<div>` to another position in the DOM tree).

¹ it would be best to put it exactly where you want the `.entry` to end up (i.e. the `.entry` and the helper div will end up being siblings).

PS: It's always better for everyone if you [mention your real purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You are right about my final objective, though not entirely about the question. I was hopping to achieve the same result adding element to DOM only once (now I need to add it to the wrapping element, then remove and add it to the parent element). The reason is that some browsers (cough, IE) punish for changing DOM tree.

Comment: @Guy: Relocating the inner div isn't going to take much either code-wise (it's just e.g. an `.appendTo()`) or performance-wise (just one element we 're moving around, and it won't affect the layout by vacating its previous position). IMHO you should not be doing this at all, but assuming there's good reason I don't think you will have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine a situation wherein for the browser to be able to compute the element's effective height, it will have to render it on the window, or at least have the element's box reflow against the current site layout. It might not be visible (as, yeah, it's instantly removed), but a situation like this will reflow the page, and the movement of the affected elements on the page *can* be seen.

Images come to mind, for example, because browsers generally have no idea what the dimensions of images are until they try to lay them out (correct me if I'm wrong there though).

So, no, I wouldn't say that this is consistent behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Implement it like this. Make a clone of app.twitter_feed, and send it to hell (Coordinates: x:-30000, y:-30000) and try whatever you like there.

```
var cloneTWFeed = $(app.twitter_feed).clone();
cloneTWFeed.css("position", "absolute").css("top","-30000").css("left","-30000");
var feed = $('<div class="entry"></div>').text(data.status).appendTo(cloneTWFeed);
console.log(feed.height());
feed.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You current code works just fine, but you never get to see the element, since just after you append it, you remove it.

The browser sees it, by the time that he takes to remove it, just after being appended.

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/2UsW3/) Example!

There I've replaced the console.log with an alert() to force the browser to wait for my response, thus enabling me to see the element on the page.

**Note:** Also works fine with console.log(), given me the 18px of height.

---

You either have the remove() wrapped on a timer to actually see the element (visually), or if the HTML markup is to intense, or the desired effect is to only collect data from the element, place your element inside an hidden one, that way you can remove it whenever you've done collecting data from it.

Answer (score -1):

If what you must acheive is an height measurement, try to add the element without visibility (see CSS:
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/visibility)

In a zone of the page that causes no problems on the element flow.